# How to get Server Name, Port and Context

Tags: java, url, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have Java Web app.

I need get its URL where it is running (e.g. `http://myserver:8080/mycontext`).

I need it because I want to be able construct URL on some resource, that has been created.

e.g. By soap request was created resource `/myresource` and I need insert into soap response reference on this resource (`http://myserver:8080/mycontext/myresource`)

And I need to be able return URL on resource even when message come from JMS.

1. Is it possible to determine application URL during startup? e.g. in `ServletContextListener`.
2. Or how it is beeing solved?

Comment: StackOverflow uses [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all those from the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object, if you can get a hold of it.

Comment: It is fine, but i must wrap all requests, because I don't know which request will be first. I advance, when first request is from soap, or JMS, so there is no HttpServletRequest.